# Why is there a dependency cycle on templated cmake project?

Tags: templates, cmake, dependencies, preprocessor

I have a project when all source files are preprocessed with custom template engine. I would want all template files to be generated first, then compiled, as separate stages, so that I do not get missing `#include`s later. In my mind that's simple - I create a target that depends on all generated files and add_dependency between the library and generated target.

Take the following structure:

```
CMakeLists
src/CMakelists.txt
src/a.c
```

And we have:

```
mkdir -p src
touch src/a.c
```

```
cat >CMakeLists.txt <<'EOF'
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generatedtimestamp
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generatedtimestamp
)
add_custom_target(generatedtarget DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generatedtimestamp)

set(GENERATED "" CACHE INTERNAL "") # bin to collect all generated files
function(template_generate A_SOURCE A_OUTPUT)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${A_OUTPUT}
    DEPENDS ${A_SOURCE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${A_SOURCE} ${A_OUTPUT}
  )
  get_filename_component(A_OUTPUT ${A_OUTPUT} ABSOLUTE)
  list(APPEND GENERATED "${A_OUTPUT}")
  set(GENERATED "${GENERATED}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
endfunction()

add_subdirectory(src)
message(STATUS ${GENERATED})
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generatedtimestamp
    DEPENDS ${GENERATED}
    APPEND
)
EOF
```

```
cat >src/CMakeLists.txt <<'EOF'
template_generate(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.c
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/a.c
)
add_executable(testtarget
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/a.c
)
add_dependencies(testtarget generatedtarget)
EOF
```

However this results in:

```
+ cmake -H. -B_build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
+ cmake --build ./_build --parallel --verbose
ninja: error: dependency cycle: src/gen/a.c -> generatedtarget -> CMakeFiles/generatedtarget -> generatedtimestamp -> src/gen/a.c
```

I do not see that dependency cycle. In my mind, the dependency is linear (`left <- right` represents that "right depends on left"):

```
testtarget -> generatedtarget -> generatedtimestamp -> gen/a.c -> src/a.c
            \-------------------------->------------/
```

Why is there a dependency cycle?

`... generatedtimestamp -> src/gen/a.c` - why does `gen/a.c` depend on `generatedtimestamp`?

Comment: JSYK the `-H` flag for setting the source directory has never been a documented feature and might one day break. On CMake >=3.13, the `-S` flag is the supported alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there a dependency cycle?

I'm going to name the participants in the cycle like so:

- **`(A)`** file: `src/a.c`
- **`(B)`** file: `<bin>/src/gen/a.c`
- **`(C)`** file: `<bin>/generatedtimestamp`
- **`(D)`** target: `testtarget`
- **`(E)`** target: `generatedtarget`

The error message in your question corresponds to the cycle (note that `CMakeFiles/generatedtarget` is just an implementation detail):

```
(B) -> (E) -> (C)
   \--<---<--*
```

Now here's what happens:

1. With the first two `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target`, you establish `(E) -> (C)`.
2. Inside `src/CMakeLists.txt`, the first lines of `template_generate` establish `(B) -> (A)`.
3. Then `add_executable` establishes `(D) -> (B)`.
4. The `add_dependencies` function then explicitly establishes `(D) -> (E)`.

   1. It *also* establishes that `(B)` -> `(E)`. This is the problem. `add_dependencies` forces the dependent to be *completely built* before the given target.
5. The `add_custom_command(APPEND)` call then establishes `(C)` -> `(B)`

So the whole graph is:

```
          /--<---<--*
(D) -> (E) -> (C) -> (B) -> (A)
   *-->--->--->-->--/
```

and you can see the original cycle in this log.

Comment: `It also establishes that (B) -> (E)` I do not understand that... Why? `forces the dependent to be completely built before the given target.` So `testtarget` dependencies, i.e. object files that are linked to an executable, now depend on `generatedtarget`? So `add_dependencies` basically does in pseudocode `foreach(i IN $<SOURCE_FILES:testtarget>) set_property(${i} OBJECT_DEPENDS generatedtarget)` - it iterates over source files of the executable and adds dependencies on sources?